# Palindrome with Array based stack and queue check

Tags: java, palindrome

For an assignment we are applying what is said in the title. i have written all the code out, but when I am compiling the code i get four errors dealing with the line 19 of code.

```
while(!myQueue<String>.isEmpty() & !myStack.isEmpty()){
```

this is the full code if it also helps

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Palindrome{
         public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String userInputConversion;
         String userInput;
         MyStack myStack = new MyStack();
         MyQueue<String> myQueue = new MyQueue<String>();
         System.out.println("Enter in a possible Palindrome. ");
         userInputConversion = scan.next();
         userInput = userInputConversion.toLowerCase();
         String s = new String();
    for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++){
        s = "" + userInput.charAt(i);
        System.out.print(s);
        myQueue.enqueue(s);
        myStack.push(s);
    }
    while(!myQueue<String>.isEmpty() & !myStack.isEmpty()){
        String deQueued = myQueue.dequeue();
        String popped = myStack.pop();
    if(deQueued == popped)
        System.out.println("Input is a palindrome. ");
    else
        System.out.println("input isnt a palindrome. ");
    }
        }
    }
    class MyStack{
    private String[] stack;
    private int top;
    public MyStack(){
    stack = new String [100];
    top = 0;
}
public String push(String pushP){
    if(top >= stack.length){
        System.out.println("Error: MyStack.push(): stack overflow");
        return "yes";
    }
    stack[top] = pushP;
    top++;
}
public String pop(){
    if(top <= 0){
        System.out.print("Error in MyStack.pop(): stack empty");
        return "n";
    }
    top--;
    return stack[top];
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    if(top == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    }
    `}
    class MyQueue<String> implements Iterable<String> {
    private String[] queue;
    private int front = 0;
    private int rear = 0;
    private int currentSize = 0;

public MyQueue(){
    queue = (String[])(new Object[1]);
    front = 0;
    rear = 0;
    currentSize = 0;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (currentSize == 0);
}
public int currentSize() {
    return currentSize;
}
public void enqueue(String String) {
    if (currentSize == queue.length - 1) {    
        resize(2 * queue.length);
    }

    queue[rear++] = String;

    if (rear == queue.length) {
        rear = 0;  
    }

    currentSize++;
}

public String dequeue() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Tried to dequeue an empty queue");
    }
    else {
        String itemToReturn = queue[front];
        queue[front++] = null; 
        currentSize--;
        if (front == queue.length) {
            front = 0;
        }
        if (currentSize == queue.length / 4) {
            resize(queue.length / 2);
        }

        return itemToReturn;
    }
}

private void resize(int capacity) {
    String[] newArray = (String[]) new Object[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++) {
        newArray[i] = queue[(front + i) % queue.length];
    }
    queue = newArray;
    front = 0;
    rear = currentSize;
}
}
```

if anyone can help that would be great or give some pointers.

Comment: And what are those errors? I'm guessing the `<String>` is the culprit. Remove it & re-compile. The type parameter should only be needed when declaring the variable.

Comment: so i fixed that part and one other error in the part. it the comes with an error "MyQueue is not abstract and does not overide method iterator<> where String is a type variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 2nd compilation error, `The type MyQueue<String> must implement the inherited abstract method Iterable<String>.iterator()`, you can either

- implement the `public Iterator<String> iterator()` method
- remove the `implements Iterable<String>` statement
- or  make MyQueue `abstract`

Making MyQueue `abstract` won't help you much & I also don't see any place in the code where you need an `iterator` or make use of the fact that `MyQueue` is `Iterable`. Being a queue, you would want to use its signature methods - `enqueue` & `dequeue`. So, you can safely go for option 2. Else to implement, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849625/2173960) should help.

You also haven't implemented the concept of [type arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) perfectly. You would want to use a `Type Parameter` in the class definition; e.g. `class MyQueue<String>` becomes `class MyQueue<T>`. Likewise the member variables & methods would also change.

You 3rd compilation error, `This method must return a result of type String` is simply because your `push()` method doesn't have a `return` statement at the end. It's better to simply make it `void`, since you're not using the returned `String "yes"` anywhere. For `StackOverflow`, you can throw an `RuntimeException`, just like you did in your `dequeue`.

Few pointers

- You've made the classic mistake of comparing Strings with `==` instead of [`.equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/2173960) in the statement `if (deQueued == popped)`.
- Make it a practice to close your [scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25790294/2173960)/resources, even though in this case there's no harm.

You have a little logical error in your `while loop` that compares the characters - I'll let you figure that one out.

Comment: You may [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer & close the question.

Comment: i do, except when adding the code where you mentioned the fixing i received a new error

Comment: it deals with this         public String dequeue() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Tried to dequeue an empty queue");
        }
        else {
            String itemToReturn = queue[front]; and says type T can't be converted to String

Comment: It should be `T itemToReturn = queue[front];` where `T` is the type parameter.

Comment: um i think i just have bad coding haha. By changing that T itemToReturn like you show causes the return itemToReturn; to have the same error of T can not be converted to String.

Comment: Yes, you would have to replace accordingly. Best go through the tutorial I provided to better understand & learn properly of its usage rather than me suggesting edits on every error you encounter.

Comment: i found out what was wrong the public dequeue was "public String dequeue" so that was causing it to try to convert. so by switching it to public T dequeue it started working except the printing in the loop which is easy compared to everything else

Answer (score 0):

First of all your making things Complex, for a simple string why do you want use stack or queue . i guess below logic would help you

```
String original, reverse = "";
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
      original = in.nextLine();

      int length = original.length();

      for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
         reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

      if (original.equals(reverse))
         System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
      else
         System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
```

Comment: why do you need to keep additional `reverse` string? you may simply loop floor(length/2) times, checking equality of original[0]  with original[length-1] then original[1] with original[length-2] etc.

Comment: in the prompt for the code we have to use both stack and queue for checking the palindrome